# Vlookup doesn't work with multiple conditions

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Can anybody help me, I don't know where the issue is. I get the following error message: "VLOOKUP evaluates to an out-of-bounds range."

[image]

The range to search in is on another sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your formula should be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B1:B&C1:C, {Sheet1!A:A&Sheet1!B:B, Sheet1!C:C}, 2, 0)))
```